# CORS error occurred to access WordPress REST API from localhost

Tags: wordpress, cors, wordpress-rest-api

I want to access WordPress REST API from localhost. My code is as follows:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2",
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
```

It is showing

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It is working fine on the same origin, but not from the outside of it.

I have added

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'  );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
```

to functions.php of Storefront theme. Still it's not working.

Comment: Looks like the response headers don't arrive. Check the HTTP requests in your browser with ctrl+shift+i.

Comment: @inf3rno Under Network -> Headers -> General Chrome is showing:
```Request URL: https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin```

Comment: "- strict-origin-when-cross-origin: Send full referrers same-origin, and the origin when cross-origin, but strip referrers when downgrading from HTTPS to HTTP." so maybe the HTTP is the problem. I would try to override the hosts file with a custom domain and add custom signed SSL to it and accept the cert in the browser. maybe it would work that way in the browser or just turn off origin checking for the dev machine by starting chrome with CLI params.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-5a656ed8cefa

Comment: Or you can change the referrer policy to something less strict for the dev machine with HTTP headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy